# How to check the count of .txt files in a folder (dir command)?

Tags: windows-xp, command-line

How can use dir command to check how many .txt files there are in a folder (for example, 
`C:\Temp\`)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
dir c:\temp\*.txt
```

This gives you a summary of the number of files matching that particular wildcard.

```
dir c:\temp\*.txt | find "File(s)"
```

If you only want to see the count and don't want to see any of the filenames.

Comment: Is this meant for PowerSheel ? Using the `*`  wildcard seems to only return "File not found"

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following. Once it has finished you'll see a summary with a count of the total matches:

```
dir *.txt /w /s
```

Answer (score 4):

If you need the count of files in a Batch variable for further processing, you may get it this way:

```
set i=0
for %%a in (*.txt) do set /a i+=1
```

After the for the `i` variable have the number of .txt files.

Answer (score 1):

At the command prompt, or in the batch script, type this:

dir|find /c ".txt"

This will get a list of all the txt files in the folder...

For ways to get a count of all types of files in a folder look here:

http://codebyjoshua.blogspot.com/2013/08/find-count-of-files-in-folder-at.html

Answer (score 1):

The perfect way to count the .txt files in a folder:

```
CD %UserProfile%\Desktop
DIR *.txt | FIND /c /i ".txt"
```

Answer (score -3):

```
for /F %i IN ('dir /b ^| find /i "." /c') DO if %i EQU 69 echo "the same"
```

Comment: How is that a solution to the question?

Comment: More explanation of what's going on and why would be useful.